# How can I stop being prompted to enter my password when installing a webapp?

Tags: password, webapps

Everytime I click on `install a webapp` it asks me to enter my password. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebApps when installing use packagekit to "route" the request to aptdaemon and handle the installation request given the environment and specifics of it. It was planned to add a "passwordless installation" exception in aptdaemon on behalf of WebApps but it got put aside after some considerations.

WARNING NOT RECOMMENDED: Provided that you know what you are doing *and* that you are aware of the risks, you could try to tweak your aptdaemon config and add pkla/cfg files to your atpdaemon config that whitelists WebApps ("unity-webapps-*").